# How to disable iOS scrollbar bounce on RadListView?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue, radlistview

I used a RadListView in my Nativescript Vue application, but I can't disable the scroll bounce on iOS. I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
// XML
<RadListView for="(thread, index) in threads" layout="linear" @loaded="listViewLoaded">
...

// TypeScript
methods: {
    listViewLoaded: function(args) {
        if (args.object.ios) {
            args.object.bounces = false;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RadListView` has the `bounces` property under the `CollectionView` instance instead of directly on the `args.object.ios`.

```js
methods: {
  listViewLoaded: function(args) {
    if (args.object.ios) {
      args.object.ios.collectionView.bounces = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that works. Can you tell me where I could find that in the docs?

Comment: I don't think its mentioned, the RadListView in particular is setup a little differently. Usually you would apply these properties directly to the `args.object.ios`, but if its within another view (like in this case), you would have to apply it there instead.